# How does one plot an oblique/slanted cylinder within the plot range?

Tags: graphics3d, built-in-symbols

A Cylinder does not seem to have an option to make it oblique. A Tube has an oblique center but does not seem to have an option to make the end caps oblique. One could plot a cylinder or tube that extends outside the plot region, to make it look oblique, but then the ends would not be closed and within the plot region. I searched StackExchange and found no mention of "oblique cylinder" or "slanted cylinder". Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can [transform](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GeometricTransforms.html) the [`Cylinder`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cylinder.html).

```
Graphics3D[
 GeometricTransformation[Cylinder[], 
  ShearingTransform[0.4, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]